# Wordpress plugin not showing in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, tinymce

I'm working on a small Wordpress plugin that should display a button in tinymce, but currently it's not showing in the bar.

Here is a part of the code:
Widget php file:

```
    function add_plugin( $plugin_array ) {
       $plugin_url = plugins_url('playstore-badge-button.js', __FILE__);
       $plugin_array['playstorebadge'] = plugins_url('playstore-badge-button.js', __FILE__);
       return $plugin_array;
    }

    function startup() {
        if ( ! current_user_can('edit_posts') && ! current_user_can('edit_pages') ) {
            return;
        }

       if ( get_user_option('rich_editing') == 'true' ) {
          add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'add_plugin' );
          add_filter( 'mce_buttons', 'register_button' );
        }
    }

    add_action('init', 'startup');
?>
```

playstore-badge-button.js:

```
(function() {
   tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.playstorebadge', {

      init : function(ed, url) {

        ed.addCommand('playstorebadgebutton_cmd', function() {
            ed.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, 'Ciao');
        });

        ed.addButton('playstorebadgebutton', {
            title : 'PlayStore Badge',
            image : url + '/button_icon.png',
            cmd : 'playstorebadgebutton_cmd'
         });
      }

   tinymce.PluginManager.add('playstorebadge', tinymce.plugins.playstorebadge);
}());
```

button_icon.png is a 20x20 png file. The plugin is installed and activated in Wordpress 3.6.1 running the latest XAMPP server in  Windows localhost. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `register_button` function ? You missed it.

```
function register_button($buttons) {
    array_push( $buttons, "|", "playstorebadge" );
    return $buttons;
}
```

[Here is a plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fiddle/), I've developed last year, almost same thing that you are trying to do, if you download and look at it, I think it'll help you.

Comment: I forgot to copy it, but there is that function. Still not showing though.